Why is this opcode valid in x86?
I wrote a small program and dumped out the compiled binary for it. For the instruction xor eax, 0x1, the opcode generated by the compiler was 83 f0 01. However, when I look at coder32, it tell me that the first byte, 0x83, corresponds to a class of instuctions and the next 3 bits are supposed to choose one of the instructions in this class. As per the website, for xor the 3 bits are 110 (6 in octal). However, what my compiler generated was 111 (7 in octal) which corresponds to cmp. I can't understand why does this opcode work? How do I go about manually disassembling these 3 bytes?

It doesn't say that "the next 3 bits are supposed to choose one of the instructions in this class.' It says that the opcode 6 goes into the reg field of the Mod/reg/rm byte. F0 is 11110000. First two bits are the mod (11). Next three bits are the opcode (110 = 6). Last three bits are the r/m (000).
